# Automatic height for WebBrowser Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I'm trying to render some html content with a WebBrowser xaml control. The html content varies in length. The control is placed within a grid with single row at the moment. I would like to place other controls (StackPanels) before and after the web browser and to get vertical scrolling across the entire layout.

```
Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <phone:WebBrowser
                Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="webBrowser1"
                Background="Black"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                IsScriptEnabled="False"                
                Visibility="Visible">            
        </phone:WebBrowser>            

        <ProgressBar Visibility="Visible" x:Name="LoadingProgress" Indeterminate="True"></ProgressBar>

    </Grid>
```

However I can only scroll the current viewport, being forced to apply a fixed height to the webbrowser.

The theoretical structure I'm aiming to is:

- scrollviewer

  - StackPanel
  - WebBrowser (probably within another stackPanel)
  - StackPanel
  - ...
  - Stackanel

and would like to scroll the scrollViewer, not the webbrowser, so the browser would automatically resize based on the content loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good blog post on MSDN that addresses this issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

The blogger was initially trying to accomplish the same thing as you, placing a browser into a scrollviewer, etc. But found that it didn't work well for larger html pages, they went with a different solution to disable scrolling and zooming in the browser control. Hope this can help:

> This worked fine until dealing with longer bodies of content; when the
>   height of the WebBrowser control was set to more than 1800px the the
>   application would crash. As it turned out, there’s a much easier way
>   to achieve the same effect.
>
> Instead of disabling hit testing on the WebBrowser control (and then
>   embedding it in a ScrollViewer to re-enabled the scrolling
>   experience), it’s possible to set meta tags in the HTML to declare
>   that the user should not be able to zoom the content.
>
> or
>
> These meta tags set the width of the viewport to 320px (to avoid
>   horizontal scrolling) and specify that the user should not be able to
>   scale the viewport. Add these meta tags to the HTML injected into the
>   WebBrowser control and the desired behaviour is achieved.

Comment: With this solution I would still end up having just the browser, without additional elements before and after. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To get the height from the webview, you can use

`window.external.notify("rendered_height=document.getElementById('yourId').offsetHeight")`

in `body.onload` and `body.onresize`

Here is a complete example of an [AdaptativeWebview](https://gist.github.com/Ouadie/78fc85965ebaf49e06d4) that handle scroll and resize

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).